# How to access docker daemon from container with other user than root

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to run a Jenkins container that builds docker images. I've started last week with docker and I'm a bit confused with the use of volumes from host and how users are handled.

I've been searching on internet and I've found a git issue were someone posted a solution to have access to the docker daemon from the container. Basically, the idea is to mound inside the Jenkins container the volumes that contain the docker bin folder and the `docker.sock` from the host like this:

```
     volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
       - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

I've done that and it works but only if I'm root. When I started to learn docker, I followed the example in a blog where, instead of directly using a jenkins image, the author copied the Dockerfiles from the jenkins image itself and its dependencies to explain the process. As part of the process, a jenkins user is created and it is the one in used when starting the container. My problem now is that I cannot make the jenkins user have access to the `docker.sock` mounted as it belongs to root and the group `docker` in the host. I tried adding the user `docker` in the Dockerfile but I still get a permission denied error from a Jenkins job when accessing the `docker.sock`. If I inspect the mounted `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the container I can see that `docker.sock` belongs to group `user` instead of `docker` so I don't know exactly what's going on when the directory is mounted. I haven't worked much with Linux so my guess is that the user `docker` doesn't exist when the directory is mounted and that it then uses a default `user` but I may probably be completely wrong.

Another thing I still don't get is, if I create a container specifically to be used as a Jenkins container and nothing else is supposed to be run there, what's the purpose of creating a specific `jenkins` user? Is there any reason why I cannot use directly the user `root`?

This is the Dockerfile I use. Thanks.

```
FROM centos:7

# Yum workaround to stalled mirror
RUN sed -i -e 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf

RUN rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__*
RUN rpm --rebuilddb -v -v
RUN yum clean all


# see https://bugs.debian.org/775775
# and https://github.com/docker-library/java/issues/19#issuecomment-70546872
ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20140324

RUN yum -v install -y \
    wget \
    zip \
    which \
    openssh-client \
    unzip \
    java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel \
    git \
    && yum clean all

#RUN /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

# Install Tini
ENV TINI_VERSION 0.9.0
ENV TINI_SHA fa23d1e20732501c3bb8eeeca423c89ac80ed452

# Use tini as subreaper in Docker container to adopt zombie processes
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/v${TINI_VERSION}/tini-static -o /bin/tini && chmod +x /bin/tini \
  && echo "$TINI_SHA  /bin/tini" | sha1sum -c -

# SET Jenkins Environment Variables
ENV JENKINS_HOME /var/jenkins_home
ENV JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT 50000
ENV JENKINS_VERSION 2.22
ENV JENKINS_SHA 5b89b6967e7af8119c52c7e86223b47665417a22
ENV JENKINS_UC https://updates.jenkins-ci.org
ENV COPY_REFERENCE_FILE_LOG $JENKINS_HOME/copy_reference_file.log

# SET Java variables
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre
ENV PATH /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin:$PATH

# Jenkins is run with user `jenkins`, uid = 1000
# If you bind mount a volume from the host or a data container,
# ensure you use the same uid
RUN useradd -d "$JENKINS_HOME" -u 1000 -m -s /bin/bash jenkins

#Not working. Folder not yet mounted?
#RUN DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock) && \

#Using gid from host
RUN groupadd -for -g 50 docker && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins

# Jenkins home directory is a volume, so configuration and build history
# can be persisted and survive image upgrades
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home

# `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` contains all reference configuration we want
# to set on a fresh new installation. Use it to bundle additional plugins
# or config file with your custom jenkins Docker image.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d

# Install Jenkins
RUN curl -fL http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/jenkins-war/${JENKINS_VERSION}/jenkins-war-${JENKINS_VERSION}.war -o /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war \
  && echo "$JENKINS_SHA /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war" | sha1sum -c -

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8192m"
ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log  --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war"

# Prep Jenkins Directories
RUN chown -R jenkins "$JENKINS_HOME" /usr/share/jenkins/ref
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins

# Expose Ports for web and slave agents
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 50000

# Copy in local config files
COPY init.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy
COPY jenkins.sh /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
COPY plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh


# Install default plugins
COPY plugins.txt /tmp/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /tmp/plugins.txt


# Add ssh key
RUN eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
RUN mkdir /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/known_hosts

COPY id_rsa /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY id_rsa /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
COPY hudson.tasks.Maven.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/hudson.tasks.Maven.xml

RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /usr/share/jenkins/ref && \
    chmod 600 /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /usr/share/jenkins/ref/hudson.tasks.Maven.xml

COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

# ssh keys for root. To use root as the user
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Switch to the jenkins user
USER jenkins

# Tini as the entry point to manage zombie processes
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was in the gid. For some reason I thought the docker gid of the group in the host was 50 but actually it was actually 100. When I changed it to be 100, the jenkins job started to work. 
I still don't know why `docker.sock` shows it belongs to group `user` instead of `docker` in the container though. If I do `cat /etc/group` in the container I see

```
root:x:0:
...
users:x:100:
...
jenkins:x:1000:
docker:x:100:jenkins
```

and in the host

```
root:x:0:
lp:x:7:lp
nogroup:x:65534:
staff:x:50:docker
docker:x:100:docker
dockremap:x:101:dockremap
```

Comment: The outside host and the container use the same numeric uid/gid, but the names (docker, jenkins, etc) can differ. That is because of [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) which give each container its own namespace for users, PIDs, filesystem paths, and so on.